# How to check for mock calls with wildcards?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am writing unit tests, and want to check for a call which has a function object, like so:

`call(u'mock', u'foobar', <function <lambda> at 0x1ea99b0>, 10)`

How do I check that the call() has all the parameters I want, without reproducing the lambda?

Edit: I wanted to clarify that I am using the `mock` library from here: http://mock.readthedocs.org/en/latest/. The `call` I showed above is a call on a `MagicMock` object, which I want to check using `assert_has_calls`.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I finally found out how to do what I want. Basically, when using `assert_has_calls`, I wanted one parameter to match regardless of what it was (because I can't recreate the `lambda` every time during test).

The way to do it is to use [`mock.ANY`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#any).

So, in my example, this could match the call:

```
mocked_object.assert_has_calls([
   call('mock', 'foobar', mock.ANY, 10)
])
```

Answer (score 16):

If you want more granularity than mock.ANY, you can make your own validator class for use in call comparisons like assert_has_calls, assert_called_once_with, etc.

```
class MockValidator(object):

    def __init__(self, validator):
        # validator is a function that takes a single argument and returns a bool.
        self.validator = validator

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return bool(self.validator(other))
```

Which can be used like:

```
import mock
my_mock = mock.Mock()
my_mock('foo', 8)

# Raises AssertionError.
my_mock.assert_called_with('foo', MockValidator(lambda x: isinstance(x, str)))

# Does not raise AssertionError.
my_mock.assert_called_with('foo', MockValidator(lambda x: isinstance(x, int)))
```

Answer (score 2):

not sure how you're building the `call`, but if it's some sort of `args`:

```
# IN THE CASE WE'RE DOING call(*args)

if all([len(args) == 4,isinstance(args[0],str),
       isinstance(args[1],str), hasattr(args[2],'__call__'),
       isinstance(args[3],int)]):
    # PASS
else:
    # FAIL
```

If you're overly concerned about getting input that is a callable that ISN'T a function, and feel it will fail the unit test silently:

```
from types import FunctionType

isinstance(lambda x: x,FunctionType) # True
```

Comment: My general way of testing this is to use `mockobject.assert_has_calls([(call('foo', 'bar', 'bla')])`. I am assuming I can't use something similar here?

Comment: @RohanDhruva I'm afraid I don't follow

Comment: This is what I'm using to test for calls: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.assert_has_calls