# Is there any value I can use for method assert_called_once_with, which would match anything?

Tags: python, mocking, python-mock

I have this function

```
def my_function(param1, param2):
    ...
    my_other_function(param1, param2, <something else>)
    ...
```

I want to test that `my_other_function` is being called with `param1` and `param2`, and I don't care about the rest

I wrote a test like this

```
@mock.patch('mymodule.my_other_function')
def test_my_other_function_is_called(my_other_function_mock):

   my_function('foo', 'bar')
   my_other_function_mock.assert_called_once_with('foo', 'bar', ?????)
```

Is there any value I can pass to the `assert_called_once_with` method (or any of the "sister" method from `MagicMock`, so that the assertion passes? Or do I have to manually get the calls list, and check each of the parameters with which the function was called?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for mock calls with wildcards?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184642/how-to-check-for-mock-calls-with-wildcards)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#any is said that you can use `unittest.mock.ANY`:

```
@mock.patch('mymodule.my_other_function')
def test_my_other_function_is_called(my_other_function_mock):

   my_function('foo', 'bar')
   my_other_function_mock.assert_called_once_with('foo', 'bar', ANY)
```